# can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Tags: python, pandas, statmodels

```
def chek_stationary(x):
    result=adfuller(x)
    label=['ADF statestic test','p value','num of legs','num of observation']
    for value,label in zip(result,label):
        print(label + ":" + result)
    if result[1] <= 0.05 :
        print ('there is evedincee null hypothesis')
        print('which means there is no root here ')
        print ('and its  stationary ')
    else :
        print ('there isnot evedence and there is root and its nun stationrary')
```

Whenever I tried this function, I got this error: `"can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str"`

What should I do ?

Comment: "what should i do ?" -- not concatenate two objects together when one is a string but one isn't? If you want more specific help, please post a [mcve], one with a clear statement of intended output and information about which line is throwing the error.

Comment: result appears to be a tuple. You can cast it to a string `str(result)` or choose the element of the tuple to print `result[0]`.

Comment: Did you mean: `print(label + ":" + value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of your situation:

```
str_var = 'aaa'
tuple_var = ('b','B')
print(str_var  + ":" +  tuple_var)
```

**Result with the same error thrown:**
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

**Fix:** - just add str() function before.

```
str_var = 'aaa'
tuple_var = ('b','B')
print(str_var  + ":" +  str(tuple_var))
```

**Result without error**: aaa:('b', 'B')